# Help with Nhibernate query?

Tags: t-sql, nhibernate

Please can anyone help me in changing the below T-SQL query to NHibernate query:

```
Select * From **TableName** Order By Convert(int,**VarcharColumnNameContainsOnlyNumbers**) Desc
```

Please note that when I used the below query I got wrong ordered data:

```
mySession.CreateCriteria<**EntityName**>()
            .AddOrder(new Order("**VarcharColumnNameContainsOnlyNumbers**", false))
            .List<**EntityName**>();
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used the below code and it's solved :)

```
mySession.CreateSQLQuery("Select * From **TableName** Order By Convert(int,**VarcharColumnNameContainsOnlyNumbers**) Desc").SetMaxResults(1).UniqueResult<string>();
```

Thanks All.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Projections in your Order

```
.AddOrder(Order.Desc(Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.Int32,
      Projections.Property("VarCharColumnName")))
```